# How can I hide partial views on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application.html.erb I am rendering a header and a navbar

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
<%= yield %>
```

On devise view I want to hide the header and the navbar and display only the login view.

Comment: you could render a different layout, where those partials are not present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could check for your devise_controller:

```
<% unless devise_controller? %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `marczking`, you could use the [`devise_controller?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#devise_controller%3F-instance_method) command in the `application` layout, or you could create a totally different layout:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout :auth, if: devise_controller?
end
```

--

> display only the login view

If you only wanted to show the header on login, you may wish to use another devise helper - [`user_signed_in?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers):

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

This would show the header / nav when the user is not signed in.